# distinct vs find - Is there any performance difference?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following format of data in my collection,

```
{
    "dName": "d1",
    "city": "c1",
    "state": "s1"
}, {
    "dName": "d2",
    "city": "c1",
    "state": "s1"
}, {
    "dName": "d2",
    "city": "c1",
    "state": "s2"
}
```

I have a compound index on all three fields combined.

`dName` is unique across documents. I want to get list of dNames, given city and state. I have found the following queries does the same,

```
db.collection.find({city: 'c1', state: 's1'}, {dName: 1, _id: 0}); -> returns [{dName: 'd1'}, {dName: 'd2'}]

db.collection.distinct('dName', {city: 'c1', state: 's1'}); -> returns ['d1', 'd2']
```

The first one returns an array of objects and seconds one returns an array of string. Other than that is there any performance improvement using one over another. I think distinct is costlier since it is trying to maintain the uniqueness of the response. Is that true?

Winning plans for both queries,

Of find query (1)

```
{
    ...
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
        "transformBy" : {
            "dName" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 0.0
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "city" : 1,
                "state" : 1,
                "dName" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "city_1_state_1_dName_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "city" : [],
                "state" : [],
                "dName" : []
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "city" : [ 
                    "[\"c1\", \"c1\"]"
                ],
                "state" : [ 
                    "[\"s1\", \"s1\"]"
                ],
                "dName" : [ 
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Of distinct query (2)

```
{
    ...
    "winningPlan": {
        "stage": "PROJECTION",
        "transformBy": {"_id": 0, "dName": 1},
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "DISTINCT_SCAN",
            "keyPattern": {
                "city": 1,
                "state": 1,
                "dName": 1
            },
            "indexName": "city_1_state_1_dName_1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "city": [],
                "state": [],
                "dName": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "city": [
                    "[\"c1\", \"c1\"]"
                ],
                "state": [
                    "[\"s1\", \"s1\"]"
                ],
                "dName": [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it  a typo in the distinct query? I reckon it must be `dName`, not `mac`.  Also the find filter probably have `_id:0`, if you get the result you claim you get. Finally, could you add result of [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) command for both queries?

Comment: Yes @AlexBlex. Those were typos. Edited it. I will add winning plans for both

Comment: Thanks for the update, but you cut off timings from the explain output, which is essential to answer which query performs better.

Comment: It was 0 for both the queries since I have less number of documents to test.

Comment: Try https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs to mock the full-scale db.

Comment: The thing is, both queries are covered, so the only difference is in return format. The former returns cursor with multiple documents, whilst the later is a single document. I'd expect the later to be a tiny little bit quicker, but be aware it may throw an error if the result exceed 16Mb document limit.

Comment: Sure, I will try with mocked data. The explanation about the difference does make sense. With find, we are dealing with the cursor and with distinct, it is directly a single document. I will go with the second approach if there is no significant difference in execution time. In my application, it is guaranteed that the list of dType won't exceed 16 Mb size. Thanks for the explanation!